# Spring Boot JPA Slave Cache

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

We are in the process of moving many of our application to the cloud - however there is one application that needs to stay in-house as it interfaces with some local hardware.

The application in question is written using Spring Boot and does 90% read operations on a MYSQL database with only occasional writes. I have setup a Master-Slave MYSQL replication where the in-house server acts as a replication slave for the cloud database server.

How do I configure Spring Boot to use the in-house database for all read operations while sending write operations to the cloud database server?

I know that I could restructure the entire application to use two different datasources - but this looks like a lot of work for something which there could be a nifty way around...?

Comment: You can use MaxScale from MariaDB. That a DB proxy. But if you send a query (INSERT/UPDATE) to the cloud and read directly the slave mostly the INSERT was not replicated. it can use a little bit. You can also setup more RULES.. The can also route on special keywords in a SELECT to read also from master like **SELECT /*MASTER*/ * FROM ....**

Comment: Thanks for suggesting MaxScale. I will look into it. Do you mean sending updates and then immediately querying them is a problem for MaxScale or for Master/Slave replication?

Comment: its nor a problem for maxscale. the replication is a little bit to slow to replicate the result from the Master to the Slave. If you identify such queries you can mark this and create a rule in maxscale that this query also go to the Master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is accomplished first by specifying the slave as part of the connection string. From [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/cmani/entry/connecting_to_a_mysql_master)

```
Connection conn = driver.connect("jdbc:mysql://master,slave1,slave2,slave3/test",
        props);
```

And then setting the connection to read only (same source):

```
conn.setReadOnly(false);
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
```

While the example shows doing it manually, if Spring is managing your connections, you can specify the slaves when creating a `DataSource` for Spring's management and then use Spring's `readOnly` transaction configuration to accomplish this for you (see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)).

Comment: Good point - I wasn't event aware that this could be a feature of the MYSQL driver itself. However after a bit of googling I stumbled upon the special syntax of 
jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://localhost:3306,localhost:3310/sakila or 
jdbc:mysql:replication://master,slave1,slave2,slave3/test

(Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)
Do I have to use this or stick to your example?